# tripleplay Animator add layer

Tags: playn

I have the following (pseudo) code

```
root = _iface.createRoot(...)

Label l = new Label("hello world");
anim = Animator.create();
anim.delay(1500).then().add(root.layer, l.layer);
anim.delay(1000).then().action(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // root.add(l);
        System.out.println("it works");
    }
});
```

the **it work's** line gets printed ok, so I assume I'm updating the animation right, but the label is never added to the scene!

If I uncomment the `root.add(l)` inside the `Runnable` it works as expected (the label is added after 1 second), but it doesn't get added with `anim.delay(1500).then().add(root.layer, l.layer);`

any idea whay I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just add the layer of a TPUI `Widget` to another layer and expect the `Widget` to render properly. A widget must be added to its parent via `Group.add`.

The animation code you are using is more designed for animating raw PlayN layer's than UI elements. UI elements are generally laid out using a `LayoutManager` which controls where the layer is positioned. If you tried to animate the layer directly, you would confuse the layout manager and generally mess everything up.

That said, it's pretty safe to animate the `Root` of the interface, because that anchors a whole UI into the PlayN scene graph.

If you really want to try what you're doing above, don't use `Animator.add` use:

```
action(new Runnable() {
  root.add(l);
});
```

(like you have above) which properly adds the `Label` to the `Root`, and triggers validation and rendering of the `Label`.